# Build sumo 0.17.1 on Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: compiling

I download sumo 0.17.1 on Ubuntu 10.10 and I get this error

```
*** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

there are  a makfile.in and makefile.am in the directory

Comment: Ubuntu 10.10 is ancient and has not had updates in quite a while; any specific reason to use it?

Comment: In the future, please include the commands you have run. For example, I downloaded X from Y, extracted it using `tar xvvzf`, moved into the newly created directory and ran `make`.

Answer (score 5):

A makefile isn't present which is preventing you from installing the software. You need to do `./configure` and a `makefile` should be generated, then you can run `make` and it will install. `./configure` checks for dependencies, and if all are fulfilled, it will then generate the file. If it doesn't generate the file it means the dependencies *aren't* fulfilled and you need to install them before re-running `./configure`

Answer (score 0):

Most packages contain a file named README or INSTALL or similar giving instructions on how to build, test, and install the package. The typical sequence (popularized by GNU) is to run:

```
./configure
make
make install
```

You usually can give a lot of flags to `configure` (check the above mentioned files, or run `./configure --help`), and you'll have to run the last command as root most of the time (running the others as root is ill-advised, and you *should* check the `Makefile` to make sure it doesn't do anything fishy, but...).

Consider carefully that by installing software from source you don't get the benefit of your distribution keeping track and applying important patches and collectiong bugfixes, integrating the software seamlessly with the other packages, and making sure it is updated with any dependencies it might have.

Comment: hi now i work on ubuntu 12.04 when apply configure I got this error: cd Downloads/sumo-0.17.1
~/Downloads/sumo-0.17.1$ ./configure
checking build system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking target system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... configure: error: newly created file is older than distributed files!
Check your system clock